# Telnet client not receiving. Python telnetlib as server

Tags: python, python-3.x, localhost, telnet, telnetlib

I am trying to send "Hello Word!" to localhost using telnetlib in python3.5. My code:

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "127.0.0.1"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, 135) # host, port, timeout

tn.write("Hello World!".encode('ascii'))
```

I have enabled telnet in my windows 10. I went to cmd and ran:

```
telnet localhost 135
```

I then got a blank screen:
[image]

After that I ran my code and it just simply finishes in 0.3s. There is no output in the terminal. It just stay blank. Why didn't "Hello World!" come up on the telnet cmd? What is happening? I'm new with this.

EDIT:

Just tried netcat client. Still doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you enabled the telnet client application in Windows 10, the command `telnet localhost 135` attempts to connect to an already running telnet server running on localhost port 135.  There was no output as I am guessing it did not successfully connect to anything.

You most likely need a telnet server, which appears to have been deprecated from recent versions of Windows due to being terribly insecure.  Microsoft recommends replacing telnet with Remote Desktop

Comment: Can you tell me how to use remote desktop in this case? Also please see the edit. I tried netcat.

Comment: I am not familiar with using python to connect to Remote Desktop, but there appear to be a number of python modules available to do just that.  You seem to be using netcat like a client, you would need a server listening to that port which you can connect these clients to.  The syntax to run a netcat server on port 135 of you local machine would be something like `nc -l -p 135` then, with that running, you should be able to use your telnet client or netcat to connect to that server